# Zend Framewok 1.12 Uppercase / Lowercase character validation error

Tags: php, regex, validation, zend-framework

One of the conditions of password field in my form is that it should have an uppercase letter a lowercase letter and a digit. To implement this I am creating my form element as shown below.

```
$password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
        $password->setAttrib('id', 'password')
                 ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
                 ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Password')
                 ->setLabel('Password'.$this->indicatorIcon('required'))
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password can\'t be left blank'))
                 ->addValidator('StringLength', true, array('min' => 8, 'max' => 30, 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should be 8 - 30 characters long'))
                 ->addValidator('Regex', true, array('pattern' => '[A-Z]', 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should contain at least one upper case letter'))
                 ->addValidator('Regex', true, array('pattern' => '[a-z]', 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should contain at least one lower case letter'))
                 ->addValidator('Regex', true, array('pattern' => '/\d/', 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should contain at least one digit'))
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

But I can only validate either a lowercase letter or an uppercase letter. The order in which I add these validators overrides the other. The one with the digit works fine.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I have tried lot's of other regular expressions and they didn't worked. Can anyone please help me make this code work or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triyng separatly the Regex for lower and upper. If you try this i think it will work.

```
$password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
        $password->setAttrib('id', 'password')
                 ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
                 ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Password')
                 ->setLabel('Password'.$this->indicatorIcon('required'))
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password can\'t be left blank'))
                 ->addValidator('StringLength', true, array('min' => 8, 'max' => 30, 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should be 8 - 30 characters long'))
                 ->addValidator('Regex', true, array('pattern' => '(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+', 'messages' => $this->indicatorIcon('error').'Password should contain at least one upper case letter and one lower case letter minimum and should contain at least one digit'))
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

I just concatenate 3 patterns in one.